# Date time error in server side

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created a web application and I'm using Date time and calendar for showing employee time sheet. its run perfectly in my system but now i've published it into the server. In server side it is  displaying the following error in datetime calculation or timesheet calculation page.

```
  String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
```

I have create whole application with more than `85 pages`. More than `40 pages` having `datetime calculation`. i've changed server datetime to system datetime but its not running. The same error occured....
I'm using windows server 2003

Please help me to fix this error ..

Comment: where do you input this datatime ? can you show us the code that the error appear ? Its for sure a different format from one to the other.

Comment: Try syncronizing regional settings on your development machine and production.
Since there is a difference between your local and your server it may have to do with what culture info is used. In sweden we use date format 2012-03-30 in US they use 12/30/03. If you don't specify what format to use when you use DateTime.ToString or DateTime.Parse (and any code that depends on it) the code will expect the format to be the format selected in the control panel applet "Region and language". I've had issues with this between environments.

Comment: Put some code of you Calculation so i can Give answer for your question why Error occur.

Answer (score 2):

```
Try This Code:


DateTime DTime = new DateTime(); 
DTime =Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Today.Date.ToShortDateString()); 
lblDate.Text = string.Format("{0:MM-dd-yy}",DTime);
```

Answer (score 0):

If it works on your machine, but not on the server, then I suspect that you are storing culture specific date format (in the database?), and parsing it using the default culture on the server.

```
 CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("de-DE");
 string germanTime = DateTime.Now.ToString(ci);
 DateTime now = DateTime.Parse(germanTime);    // Can cause error if the current thread or machine's culture is not German
```

If you're saving DateTime values in the database, then you should be using `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` to prevent these type of problems.  You can also try to configure the [culture on the server machine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508.aspx) to match the culture format of the date time being parsed, but it's not as robust.

Hopefully, your web application has not ended up storing multiple date formats in your database or else it is going to be a mess.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using CultureInfo in convertion? If not try to use Convert.ToDateTime http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9xk1h71t(v=vs.90).aspx